# Rotating vectors in space and high precision in C++

Tags: c++, precision

This is my function to compute 3D rotation in C++ defined by an angle in radiant around axis.

```
 Vector rotate(const Vector& axis, const Vector& input, const double angle)    {
    double norm = 1/axis.norm();

    if(norm != 1)
        axis *= norm;

    double cos = std::cos(angle);
    double mcos = 1 - cos;
    double sin = std::sin(angle);

    double r1[3];
    double r2[3];
    double r3[3];

    double t_x, t_ym t_z;


    r1[0] = cos + std::pow(axis.x, 2)*mcos;
    r1[1] = axis.x*axis.y*mcos - axis.z * sin;
    r1[2] = axis.x*axis.z*mcos - axis.y * sin;

    r2[0] = axis.x*axis.y*mcos + axis.z*sin;
    r2[1] = cos + std::pow(axis.y, 2)*mcos;
    r2[2] = axis.x*axis.z*mcos - axis.x * sin;

    r3[0] = axis.x*axis.z*mcos - axis.y * sin;
    r3[1] = axis.z*axis.y*mcos - axis.x * sin;
    r3[2] = cos - std::pow(axis.z, 2) * mcos;

    return Vector(t_x, t_y, t_z);
}
```

The thing is if you try yourself to rotate the vector a `n` times `pi/4` where `n multiple of 4` (so you do complete revolution around the axis by doing four quarter of rotations) the error will propagate pretty fast.

Example (where `err = input-output`):

```
input: (1.265, 3.398, 3.333)
rotation axis: (2.33, 0.568, 2.689)

n: 8 (so two completes revolutions)
output: (1.301967, 1.533389, 4.138940)
error: (0.038697, -0.864611, 0.805940)


n: 400 (so 100 completes revolutions)
error: (472..., 166..., 673...)
```

What can I do ?

Constraints:

- Rotations are not predictable so not possible to do something like `angle = pi/4 *n % 2*pi` like @molbdnilo suggests. Because I have to chain translations and rotations to test if there's a collision.

Comment: you should normalize the vectors before calculating the error. This is something that you can include easily in your rotation function and the difference in lenght just distracts from the part of the error that you make in the angle

Comment: You mean normalize the `input` vector ?

Comment: normalize both. Or just normalize the output to the lenght of the input

Comment: You could use quaternions to keep more accuracy. You'll have axis and amount of rotation. But if the axis changes then it's not really possible since every part has inaccuracies.

Comment: btw if you do lots of rotations and accuracy matters you should consider using spherical coordinates

Comment: @tobi303 I thought about spherical coordinates but I need to do a lot of collision detection with a point cloud that is described in the Cartesian coordinate system.

What do you mean by normalize both ? `input` and which one ? `axis` is normalised in the first line of `rotate`.

Comment: you can do the rotations in spherical coordinates and translate them to cartesian only when needed

Comment: Instead of rotating a vector just a bit many times, rotate the original vector by the accumulated rotation every time.

Comment: @tobi303 ok so I'll convert into spherical coordinates at the beginning of `rotate` and convert backward in at the end. I'll try it.

Comment: @molbdnilo of course it will work like this but in my case I perform lots of small rotations over time and I can't predict the number.

Comment: @Deewy errm no thats not what I meant and I would expect this to be as inaccurate as what you have now.

Comment: what I meant is: dont store the cartesian coordinates, but spherical ones (where rotation is trivial) and **only when needed** transform to cartesian

Comment: @tobi303 I use cartesian all the time around it

Comment: @Deewy You don't need to predict anything, you only need a running total of the rotations (normalised to `[0, 2π)`, probably), along the lines of `rotation += rotation_step; result = rotate(original, rotation)`

Comment: @molbdnilo, This can't work in my case, it's not my case but imagine that this rotate method is used in a game with a camera and controlled by user input. You can't know how long the user press the key to rotate the camera until she stop pushing it. And you can't make her wait that she unpress the key for rotation to perform the rotation. And you can't forbid the player to turn around itself forever. I actually don't think they do it like that in game engines but I have a similar situation where the rotation have to be done right away to do the next computation.

Comment: btw even if you might be better off using sphericals imho the question as it stands is quite interesting. Sometimes it doesnt make much sense to use sphericals and an accurate way to rotate a vector in cartesians is needed

Comment: @Deewy: You still can, and should, use molbdnilo's suggestion. If the user's holding down a key, you have to repeatedly do rotations. The expense of those rotations is the same regardless of whether you are coming from the original or the incremented position, so track the total requested angle and always transform from the original.

Comment: @Deewy what molbdnilo propose is to accumulate rotation from the origin and use it when needed, that's all and pretty fine.

Comment: @Richard Yes this sound a nice solution but again I can't in my context, there's nothing to do with user input. It was my first thought and then I had to drop it out.

Comment: @Deewy: maintain the original coordinates in an object along with the rotated representation.

Comment: What's the real reason you can't use that solution?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I am considering quaternions now, I should have done it before. My rotations are done all the time in the same plane so axis will not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) and the performances are way better.

Though this is not the solution as @ComicSansMs points it out:

> Avoid chaining the float operations in the first place!

So combining a new algorithm and using Rodrigues' formula was ok.

I suspect mistakes in my first matrix implementation.

Thanks everyone for your answers and insights.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the typical problems that you can run into with `float`s.

Floating point numbers are pretty exact on singular operations. In fact, for many operations you are guaranteed to get the most exact result that can be represented in the format, so any rounding errors that you get are solely due to fitting it into the representation.

However, as soon as you start chaining floating point operations, even those errors can accumulate. If you are lucky, you can make your algorithm numerically stable, so that the rounding errors cancel each other out in the end and you always stay in the ballpark of the correct result. Getting this right can be quite a challenge though, especially for complex computations. For instance, in your particular implementation, there is lots of potential for [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) introducing large rounding errors into the computation chain.

The easier solution is: Avoid chaining the float operations in the first place! Or to be more precise: Only chain those parts which you can keep numerically stable. Since you mentioned this is for a computer game: In a game you transform the geometry according to the camera matrix each frame. You never touch the geometry in memory, instead you simply adjust the camera matrix. That way, your source geometry is always fresh and the rounding error in each frame is simply the error from that single transformation.

Similarly, you usually don't update the camera matrix incrementally. Instead, you read the player's position and view and build the complete matrix from scratch from those vectors. Now the only challenge that you have left is make sure that you don't accumulate errors into the player position and view, but this is *much* easier than ensuring stability at the other end of the transformation pipeline.

Comment: I thought that `double` have more precision than `float`. Sadly I can't predict at all and am obliged to chain. No camera involved in my problem but I need to chain translations and rotations to check collisions. I don't see at all how I can avoid it.
Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @Deewy More precision will simply delay the problem, what you need is a stable algorithm. Try chaining translations and rotations in a way that is stable. For instance, converting user input into a vector offset and then adding and renormalizing vectors each frame should work. Just be sure to not mess up your source geometry!

Answer (score 0):

Just store the original base vector and the rotation angle together, and do the calculation every time you need the current rotated value. You can cache this and invalidate every time the angle changes, but *always* work from the original base vector and total aggregate rotation.

Presto! No cumulative errors, because no chained calculations.

Also, if you're concerned about cumulative errors in the angle itself, store *that* in degrees and convert to radians when required. Again, `pi` is touched once in the degree->radian conversion, and you don't have a chain of approximate `pi/n` values contributing more errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and discretize your rotations so that they add up to multiples of pi/2. You clamp your rotation value to the closest discretized value and then do the calculation. If you find one small enough it will be still perceived as smooth and you should not accumulate an error.